# How to get innertext of heading on grid card click?

Tags: javascript, arrays, css-grid

Please help me to get innerText of heading from grid card.

CSS File ;

```css
.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.posts {
  width: 13rem;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  height: 17rem;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get innerText of heading if I click on grid3 and so on through Javascript ?

Comment: What is grid3? Do you mean, if you click on the box with the title 'Heading 3' you want the text 'Heading 3' to be stored in a variable to do something with later?

Comment: `posts` ?? you mean `post`. `posts` could eventually be a parent element (so, instead of the container1... (why the "1"? ))

Comment: @JackBashford Yes, this is what I exactly need but please remember there are more tags in posts div like img, span, etc.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan because I have one more container with class "container" in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming grids refer to the `div.posts` elements, you can just use the the document method [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to retrieve a list of all the grids, use the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate through the retrieved list of grids and then add a click listener to each grid that will retrieve the heading element's inner text.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const grids = document.querySelectorAll('div.posts');
grids.forEach(grid => grid.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(grid.childNodes[0].textContent);
  alert(grid.childNodes[0].textContent);
}));
```

```css
.container1 {display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; column-gap: 10px; justify-content: space-evenly;}
.posts {width: 13rem; margin: 10px auto 10px auto; height: 17rem; background: white; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 1</h3></div>
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 2</h3></div>
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 3</h3></div>
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 4</h3></div>
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 5</h3></div>
  <div class="posts"><h3>Heading 6</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, we could do this by event delegating too ? or am I overlooking

Comment: @Codenewbie Event delegating would work too yes.

Comment: @AndrewL64, This is not working, if there are more tags in div with class "posts" like img, span, etc.

Comment: @RahulRajput Check updated code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewL64 your code works after some changes.

Answer (score 1):

> We can do this by [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) I guess, I just tried it as an other way tbh

- Try to understand comments before implementing this way, Thanks @Roko for his valuable time to provide feedback

```js
document.querySelector(".container1").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if(e.target && e.target.closest(".posts")){
        console.log(e.target.textContent)
   }else{
    return;
   }
})
```

```css
.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.posts {
  width: 13rem;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  height: 17rem;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3>Heading 6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using Event delegation on a component unrelated element like `".container1"` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Roko, I appreciate :), helps me learn too, may I know what exactly is "component unrelated element",

Comment: You're using `target` the wrong way. All it takes is to have say: `<h3><b>Heading</b> 1</h3>` - and watch your code fail.

Comment: yeah true, it only works if there is no change made to the structure ... agree

Comment: Also, use `textContent` instead of `innerText`

Comment: sure got you why (guess for preventing security attacks), Thanks a lot, I'm like why not use or how to correctly use event delegation ... any references are much appreciated

Comment: The proposed event delegation is *"ok"*. but it should be in relation to a parent component. If a child component is say `".post"` you attach it to `".posts"` (parent), not to an arbitrary `.container1` which could change just because of trying to change CSS styles. Also, **never use `target`** without `.closest()`: so, in your case should be `event.target.closest(".posts")`. `["DIV","H3"]` is simply wrong. (If you ever see yourself using `Event.target` without `closest()` - you better know what you're doing.)

Comment: Thanks a ton mate, really makes sense ... Lot to learn 

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code which may help you. By add a onclick function.

HTML :

```
<div class="container1">
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
    <h3 onclick="GetInnerText(this.innerHTML)">Heading 6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function GetInnerText(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

Reference Link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-jdojuj?file=styles.css,index.html,script.js)

Comment: Stop using inline JS `on*` handlers. Use addEventListener instead. JS should be in one place only — and that's the respective JS tag or file.